# Oracle XMLSequence attribute name and value conversion

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am using XML-based auditing for our Oracle system. There are triggers in place on each table to create an XML representation of the record being inserted or updated into a single audit table in our database. The capturing of the audit data is working properly, however I am having issues extracting the information using Oracle's XML parsing utilities.

Using our audit table as an example, the audit table has an XML column(CLOB datatype) like the following:

```
<Audit ev='MSGADT0052$' un='ANSAR' dt='09/06/2013 16:39 '/>
<bo n='EntityDocumentBO'/>
<A n='DocExpiryDate' nv='24-07-2015' ov='05-10-2018'/>
<A n='DocDescr' nv='National ID' ov='National ID'/>
<A n='DocReceivedDate' nv='09/06/2013 16:39 ' ov='24-11-2009 '/>
```

I would like to be able to parse the XML into one of two formats.

- Each attribute name within the ROW element would be a column and each attribute value would be the value beneath the column, OR
- Each attribute name and value combination would be on it's own row

can anyone please help me with a code to serve my purpose as search and tried other old threads but i couldnt end up with a result because of luck of knowledge in XML.
thank you...

Comment: That isn't valid XML - does your real CLOB have a root node?

Comment: <auditrec></auditrec>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLSequence is deprecated from 11g. Here's an XMLTable approach that gets the Audit attributes and the A attributes as columns:

```
select x.*
from audit_table a
cross join XMLTable('for $i in /auditrec
    for $j in $i/A
      return <row ev="{$i/Audit/@ev}" un="{$i/Audit/@un}" dt="{$i/Audit/@dt}"
        n="{$j/@n}" ov="{$j/@ov}" nv="{$j/@nv}"/>'
  passing XMLType(a.clob_col)
  columns ev varchar2(11) path '@ev',
    un varchar2(5) path '@un',
    dt varchar2(10) path '@dt',
    n varchar2(20) path '@n',
    ov varchar2(16) path '@ov',
    nv varchar2(16) path '@nv'
) x;
```

```
EV          UN    DT         N                    OV               NV             
----------- ----- ---------- -------------------- ---------------- ----------------
MSGADT0052$ ANSAR 09/06/2013 DocExpiryDate        05-10-2018       24-07-2015      
MSGADT0052$ ANSAR 09/06/2013 DocDescr             National ID      National ID     
MSGADT0052$ ANSAR 09/06/2013 DocReceivedDate      24-11-2009       09/06/2013 16:39
```

I've restricted the column sizes quiet a bit to reduce scrolling here, so you'd need to set those to an appropriate length for your actual data. And you could include the `bo` node's `n` attribute as another column if you needed that.

Comment: thank you very much Alex and sorry for the late reply as this task almost got canceled. i`ve looked for many solutions online but i think this is the best one so far :).   i have a question. can we replace the cross join with a normal joint based on lets say AUDIT_TABLE.E_ID

Comment: @user1744446 - it's a cross join because of the `passing` clause; that is effectively a join condition (kind of). You can still filter on a particular value for `a.e_id`, or even on `a.e_id = x.un` if that was an ID, to see if it either does or doesn't match. Not quite sure what you're asking though.

Comment: i mean cross join dose not return a realistic number of records. lets say that the xml records above belongs to one record in audit table(e_id = 1). will this solution  return only that record asa result or it will cross it with other record in the table.

Comment: @user1744446 - each XML document will be converted to relational data, once per row it appears in. If you have 100 rows, and each XML expands to three relation rows as in this example, then your complete result set would be 300 rows. The `passing XMLType(a.clob_col)` means only that row's XML is used. Each row in `x` is related ('joined', if you like) to its original row in `a`. You don't get a cartesian product in this case.